# Как адаптировать виджеты вк?

Tags: html, css, vkontakte-api, адаптивная-верстка, виджет

Подскажите, как то вообще возможно адаптивить виджет вк? Во время его генерации можно задавать ширину виджета, но она задается в пикселях в процентах никак. Возможно ли каким то образом влиять на эту ширину на разных разрешениях экрана?

Comment: Смотря что за виджеты. У некоторых можно указать автоматическую ширину, которая будет подставляться в зависимости от ширины родительского блока.

Comment: @terron в моем случае это виджеты группы и комментов, и там и там указывается фиксированная ширина в пикселях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждого виджета есть подробная документация, ссылка на которую находится под редактором самого виджета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я и написал в своем комментарии, большинство виджетов, включая [виджет комментариев](https://vk.com/dev/widget_comments) и [виджет сообществ](https://vk.com/dev/widget_community), умеют подстраиваться под ширину родительского блока. Чтобы включить подобное поведение у виджета комментариев, необходимо просто не указывать параметр `width`. А у виджета сообществ - параметру `width` задать значение `auto`.